# firebird stored procedure not using index, but the same query does

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I've got a database with characterset defined as UTF8. A table VSL_STATIC_DATA with a varchar(60) field called VESSEL_NAME with UNICODE_CI_AI collation, with an ascending index on that field. Another table called TABLE_PORTS, with field PORT_ID as it's primary key which is the FK in the VSL_STATIC_DATA table ( PORT_OF_REG_ID)

When I run the following query, it uses the indexes for searching on vessel by name and then uses index to link with the port of registry:

```
SELECT FIRST (5) SKIP (0)
  VSL.VESSEL_ID,
  VSL.UPDATE_TIME,
  VSL.VESSEL_NAME,
  VSL.CALL_SIGN,
  VSL.MMSI,
  VSL.IMO_NUM,
  VSL.LOA,
  VSL.WIDTH,
  VSL.NRT,
  VSL.GRT,
  VSL.DWT,
  PORT.PORT_ID,
  PORT.PORT_NAME
FROM
  VSL_STATIC_DATA VSL     
LEFT JOIN
  TABLE_PORTS PORT
    ON VSL.PORT_OF_REG_ID = PORT.PORT_ID
WHERE VSL.VESSEL_NAME LIKE 'TE%'
```

But, if now I put the exact same query in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FIND_VESSEL_BY_NAME(
  VSL_NAME VARCHAR(60),
  FIRST_N INTEGER,
  SKIP_N INTEGER)
RETURNS(
  VESSEL_ID BIGINT,
  UPDATE_TIME BIGINT,
  VESSEL_NAME VARCHAR(60),
  CALL_SIGN VARCHAR(10),
  MMSI BIGINT,
  IMO INTEGER,
  LOA SMALLINT,
  WIDTH SMALLINT,
  NRT INTEGER,
  GRT INTEGER,
  DWT INTEGER,
  PORT_OF_REG_ID BIGINT,
  PORT_OF_REG VARCHAR(75))
AS
BEGIN
  /* Procedure body */
  FOR
    SELECT FIRST (:FIRST_N) SKIP (:SKIP_N)
      VSL.VESSEL_ID,
      VSL.UPDATE_TIME,
      VSL.VESSEL_NAME,
      VSL.CALL_SIGN,
      VSL.MMSI,
      VSL.IMO_NUM,
      VSL.LOA,
      VSL.WIDTH,
      VSL.NRT,
      VSL.GRT,
      VSL.DWT,
      PORT.PORT_ID,
      PORT.PORT_NAME
    FROM
      VSL_STATIC_DATA VSL     
    LEFT JOIN
      TABLE_PORTS PORT
        ON VSL.PORT_OF_REG_ID = PORT.PORT_ID
    WHERE VSL.VESSEL_NAME LIKE :VSL_NAME || '%'
    INTO
      :VESSEL_ID,
      :UPDATE_TIME,
      :VESSEL_NAME,
      :CALL_SIGN,
      :MMSI,
      :IMO,
      :LOA,
      :WIDTH,
      :NRT,
      :GRT,
      :DWT,
      :PORT_OF_REG_ID,
      :PORT_OF_REG
  DO
  SUSPEND;
END;
```

This does not use the index. I'm calling it using this sql:

```
select * from find_vessel_by_name( 'te', 10, 0)
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?
Just for information, the purpose of this is to implement incremental search for vessel by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using **starts with :VSL_NAME**  instead of **like :VSL_NAME || '%'**, but in this case you can't use additional wildchars.

Comment: That did it! It doesn't explain why the above didn't work in stored procedure, but did in direct query, but still, your alternative did solve my problem :) Thanks!

Comment: @AvnirSoni Well, because it finally showed to optimizer that all the inputs are in form 'te%' but not '%te'. Such stuff is highly DBMS-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Index on VESSEL_NAME cannot be used in the stored procedure, because of bound variable (and, probably, `||` operation - the optimizers are not perfect sometimes).

Recall that plan is calculated once, but executed for any input.

Consider e.g. `find_vessel_by_name('%te',...)` - here the index will not be useful. And `find_vessel_by_name(NULL,...)` - what should do this one?

You need some way to force the index usage.

Comment: I tried removing the `||` and passing in the argument as `te%`. Makes no difference. Removing the bounds (assuming you mean first/skip) also didn't make any difference.

Comment: @AvnirSoni Yes, because it's a variable. How could the optimizer know that using index is _always_ better than full table access? For 'te%' index is better, but for '%te' full access is better. If in doubt, it chooses full access. You have _to force_ index usage yourself.

Comment: I'm still missing something. Even if I remove the % from everywhere, pass in the `'te'` as the argument, in the procedure use the argument directly, without appending `'%'`, still it refuses to use index. In all cases, if it is a straight query, it uses index. That baffles me :-) Unless what you're saying is that in the stored procedure the text that is passed in as a variable _could_ contain wildcard character at the start and so it chooses to never use an index!

Comment: @AvnirSoni Yes, it _could_ contain any wildcards. And they _should_ work as expected. You can easily check it yourself.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, it does make sense. Thanks for taking the time for explaining this to me :-)